# py3k default to byte instead of string

Tags: string, python-3.x

Just switching from Python2 to Python3 and the new string system is a real pain (or rather I'm not understanding its true benefit).

Is there any way to make it default to the old style bytes system without having to put a b before every string.  I send a lot of commands via sockets and the code looks just ugly - i.e.

```
conn.sendall(b'k\n')
```

I tend to use this more than I worry about unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. And from what I gather you don't think it is a pain, and you do understand the benefit, you just think the b'' is ugly, which doesn't seem to be a very good reason to me.

Separating binary and text data is a great simplification in almost all cases. The need to prefix binary data with a b is a small price to pay for that.

Comment: I'm slowly getting used to it - When constructing strings and passing to a socket I have to use .encode() but I'm trying not to fight progress to hard!

Comment: Well, you only have to use .encode() if you are constructing unicode strings and then need to pass them. Are you sure you can't construct byte-strings from the start?